# Question on measure zero set of initial conditions in dynamical systems

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems

[Update] Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed, bounded, convex set with measure $m(S)>0$ and let an autonomous dynamical system (system of ODEs) be given by

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x),$$

where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, each $f_i$ is a polynomial function and $x$ takes values in $S$. The system exhibits a (bounded) potential function $V$ (the time derivative is non-positive and is zero at the equilibria and $S$ is flow invariant.

I would like to claim that starting from a generic initial condition in $S$ (all but a *zero measure* set of conditions) the system converges to an equilibrium and the eigenvalues of corresponding Jacobian have nonpositive real part. Is this true? If the claim is not true is there a simple counterexample?

Comment: What do you mean by "eigenvalues of an equilibrium"? Is the equilibrium a matrix?

Comment: I think OP is thinking in terms of Lie.

Comment: I fixed it, i meant the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix

Answer (score 1):

[Updated] First you need to assume that $V$ vanishes on some non-empty set $T\subset S$. Otherwise $\dot{x}=-x^3$, $V(x)=x^2$, and $S=[1,2]$ is a counter-example.

Now I assume that $T$ is non-empty. Then the answer to the first question is yes,provided that the $S$ is flow invariant (otherwise, take a saddle point and pick a tube around its stable eigenvector). If $S$ is flow invariant, then the system converges asymptotically to some point in $T$. This is called the invariance principle.

In either case, I do not see why you need to mention measure zero sets here.

The answer to the second question is yes. If there is a positive eigenvalue, the system is not locally stable along the direction of the corresponding eigenvector. This is called Lyapunov's indirect method (which essentially says you can use a taylor series expansion and reduce to the linear case).

Comment: First of all the first thing which is wrong is that you mention there is a unique equilibrium. All local minima of $V$ are equilibria.

Comment: If V is strictly decreasing, there is only one local minima

Comment: Among each trajectory, $V$ is strictly decreasing. Starting from a different point you got a different trajectory that can move you to a different minimum, no? Can you prove your argument?

Comment: What will happen at the boundary between these two regions ?

Comment: Alternatively, initialize your system at the second equilibrium. that's a trajectory along which your Lyapunov function is not decreasing. if your want to say the Lyapunov function is strictly decreasing in a small neighborhood of the equilibrium, then you should say so.

Comment: and I still don't understand the role of measure zero sets in the discussion of stability.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I changed a bit the question to be more clear. I agree that you can establish convergence to equilibrium, however the system can have more than one equilibria. Furthermore, even if an equilibrium is unstable, it still may exhibit a stable manifold(to which is the limit of). For example, trivially if I start from an unstable equillibrium, I will stay (converge) there. I would like to argue that starting from a generic point (i.e., with probability one) I not only converge to an (arbitrary) equilibrium, but futhermore to a stable one.

Comment: If the system converges to an equilibrium with probability 1, it necessarily has to be to a stable eq. point, since the dimension of the stable manifold of an unstable eq. point will always be less than n. So the 'furthermore' point doesn't really add anything extra.

Comment: Anyhow, what happens to your potential function on an unstable manifold ? I don't see how unstable manifold can exist if V is always decreasing.

Comment: First of all, the number of the unstable equilibrium points can be uncountable. Why can it not be the case that although each stable manifold is of dimension less than n, their union has positive measure.